# How to keep listview headers (or specific type list items) from scrolling with the listView content

Tags: android

There must be a way to do this. How can you tell a ListView that has a header to not scroll it when the user scrolls the contents? Just like in the contacts app from google. Where the letter 'a' keeps stuck in position so that a user always see what column the content applies to. I already used the code of Jeff Sharkey's SeparatedListAdapter. But the header list items will scroll with the list items and i want it to get stuck at the top(until the next header hits it). The iphone also has this option when you look in contacts, the code line for this is "titleForHeaderInSection".

Let me know.

Kind regards,

Charx

Comment: @user632538 - Welcome to Stackoverflow, Charx! Cool name..

Answer (score 0):

I do this in one of my apps by creating a linerlayout as the root, then the first child can be a FrameLayout, followed by the ListView. Your listview goes into a relative layout and should automatically fill the remainder of the area.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
       height="50px"
       width="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
     <RelativeLayout>
       <ListView
         height="fill_parent"
         width="fill_parent">
       </ListView>
     </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry, I don't have my IDE in front of me, so I can't give you exact code, only pseudocode.

Comment: And do you also use the setContentVeiw(R.layout.yourXmlExample)

Comment: @user632538 - Yes, you have to do that whenever you create/use a custom layout. It's how you bind an activity to an XML file. The reason you don't do that now is you are using the default listview, which as you know, consumes the whole screen and isn't open to modification.